# Chained jQuery promises execute early

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, promise

I'm struggling with jQuery's promises and animations. This is a simplified case:

```
var title = $('#intro h2');
title.fadeOut(2000).promise()
    .then(function () { title.fadeIn(4000); } )
    .then(function () { title.css( {'background-color':'red'} ); } );
```

I would expect the heading (`$('#intro h2')`) to fade out, then fade in, and then for its background colour to change to red. Instead, the background changes to red **before** the heading fades back in.

What's going on?

How can I use promises to ensure the right sequence of events?

Comment: It looks like you should be using jQuery's `queue` for this behavior rather than `promise`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `then` callback does not return a promise, so the promise chain does not know what to wait for. It doesn't wait for `undefined`. Use

```
title.fadeOut(2000).promise().then(function(){
    return title.fadeIn(4000).promise();
//  ^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^^^
}).then(function() {
    title.css({'background-color':'red'})
})
```

Notice that this animation could also be done using the animation queue alone:

```
title.fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(4000, function(){title.css('background-color','red')})
```

Comment: I did know about chaining `$foo.fadeOut(t).fadeIn(t2);` but my actual use case is more complicated and the example was the simplest I could think of to show what I was experiencing. The actual use-case involves creating helper functions to standardise animation behaviour (timing, easing, returning promises) across multiple animation effects. The problem occurred without the complexity of the helper functions, so I only gave this simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise of the fade-in animation from your first `then()` callback.

Otherwise, the promise chain doesn't have anything to wait for, so it executes immediately.

```
title.fadeOut(2000).promise()
    .then(function () { return title.fadeIn(4000).promise(); })
    .then(function () { title.css( {'background-color':'red'} ); });
```